# Get Child Node IDs in JSTree

Tags: javascript, jstree

I need to be able to get the child node ids.  I have JS tree entirely expanded on load, but I cannot get the child nodes, as it seems to load them some time after.

Example JSON being retrieved though AJAX:

`[{"id":"L2","text":"L2","state":  {"opened":true},"children":[{"id":"L1711","state":{"opened":true},"text":"cat"},{"id":"L1712","state":{"opened":true},"text":"dog"},{"id":"L1743","state":{"opened":true},"text":"bird"}]}]`

I need to get the IDS such as L1712, L1743, etc.

JS:

```
if ($('#features-tree').is(':empty')) {
                    $('#features-tree').jstree({
                        'core': {
                            'themes': {
                                'name': 'proton',
                                'icons': false
                            },
                            'data': {
                                'url': function (node) {
                                    return 'retrieveNodes?imageId=' + _this.imageId;
                                },
                                'data': function (node) {
                                    return { 'id': node.id };
                                },
                            }
                        },
                    });
```

However, if I do a console log of:

`console.log($('div#features-tree > ul > li').html());`

I simply get back:

`<i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon-hidden"></i>Loading ...</a>`

How can I get the nodes that are replacing the `Loading...` part?  I need to get them so I can interact with another part of the page.

Comment: 1. Use `$.getJSON` to grab data from server 2. get IDs from object, 3. use object to build the tree

Answer (score 0):

You can get children IDs list by process input json directly

```js
let a=[{"id":"L2","text":"L2","state":  {"opened":true},"children":[{"id":"L1711","state":{"opened":true},"text":"cat"},{"id":"L1712","state":{"opened":true},"text":"dog"},{"id":"L1743","state":{"opened":true},"text":"bird"}]}];

let r= a.flatMap(x=>x.children.map(y=>y.id));

console.log(r);
```